# jQuery load question with slideDown effect

Tags: jquery, ajax

it's my first post here on stackoverflow, but read a lot and learning.

I using a jquery function that loads post in wordpress themes with .load function.

But now i have one problem that i can't solve by myself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$("#thumbs a").click(function(){
var post_id = $(this).attr("rel") 
$("#your_post_here").slideDown("1200", function () {
$("#your_post_here").html("<img src='http://localhost/wp-content/themes/insp/images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
$("#your_post_here").load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/triqui-ajax/",{id:post_id});
});

    return false;

});

$("a.close").live("click", function(){ 
    $("#intro").slideUp(1200);
    return false;
});
```

});

The problem is i can't get it to slideDown before it's load. do someone have an idea of what can be wrong?

Everyting works fine except slideDown effect

**Edit:**

Maybe i get it wrong, put can't really get it to work.

I put it like this, is this wrong?

```
$("#thumbs a").click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel") 
$("#your_post_here").slideDown("200", function () {
    $("#your_post_here").html("<img src='http://localhost/wp-content/themes/insp/images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
    $("#your_post_here").load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/triqui-ajax/",{id:post_id});
});
```

Comment: Did you wrap this in the $(document).ready (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)? I forget to do this sometimes, and it causes UI effects to not happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the `.load()` in the `.slideDown()`'s callback.

```
$("#your_post_here").slideDown("200", function () {
    $("#your_post_here").html("<img src='http://localhost/wp-content/themes/insp/images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
    $("#your_post_here").load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/triqui-ajax/",{id:post_id});
});
```

// EDIT:

```
$("#your_post_here").slideDown("200", function () {
    $(this).html("<img src='http://localhost/wp-content/themes/insp/images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
    $(this).load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/triqui-ajax/",{id:post_id});
});
```

Comment: I have edited how i have it know, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: Hehe thank you very much, i hate my self sometimes. Need to set an height of div your_post_here and "display: none;" :)

Comment: Whoops, but it happens to best of us. ;)